# Mostrar datos mysql en una tabla con php

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

tengo un input donde pongo una consulta y me devuelve los datos de la consulta,pero quiero que los datos que me devuelva estén en una tabla para que se puedan visualizar mejor.Actualmente me sale algo así:

nombre apellido nombre apellido nombre apellido

y me gustaría que saldría en una tabla o algo para poder diferenciar mejor los datos.
Este es el código que tengo para ejecutar la consulta y mostrar los datos.

```
<?php  
session_start();



$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bbdd");
if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
    echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $conexion->connect_errno . ") " . $conexion->connect_error;
}


$consultaa=$_POST["consultaa"];

    $queryy = mysqli_query($conexion, "$consultaa");


    if (!$queryy){
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conexion));
    }
    if(mysqli_num_rows($queryy) > 0){
       $response='success';
    } 

    $column=mysqli_num_fields($queryy);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryy))

 {
    for ($i=0; $i < $column; $i++) { 

?>  
 <td><?php echo $row[$i];?></td>

 <?php      
    }


 }

?>
```

Comment: Revisando esto, veo que tienes un grave fallo de seguridad por inyección SQL, deberías mirar este hilo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php/53134#53134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la parte dónde muestras los datos:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryy)) {
    for ($i=0; $i < $column; $i++) {
        ?>
        <td><?php echo $row[$i]; ?></td>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Debes modificarlo para que se cree la estructura de la tabla completa, en tu código, solo indicas que se creen los tags HTML td y por tanto, te faltan los table y los tr, sería algo así:

```
echo "<table>"; // Creas la tabla
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryy)) {
    echo "<tr>"; // Por cada fila
    for ($i=0; $i < $column; $i++) {
        ?>
        <td><?php echo $row[$i]; ?></td>
        <?php
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Luego solo tienes que darle el formato que desees con CSS.